# filter grideview work with having condition in search function in criteria?

Tags: yii

i have a grideview by this code

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'lecture-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header'=>'name',
        'type' => 'raw',
       // 'name'=>'name',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->name,Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/uploads/" . $data->name)',

    ),
    array(
        'header'=>'pages',

        'value'=>'$data->slide_num'
    ),
    array(
        'header'=>'type',

        'value'=>'$data->type'
    ),
    array(
        'header'=>'Size',

        'value'=>'$data->size'
    ),
   // 'subject.name'
    array (
        'header'=>'subject',
        'value' => 'ucfirst($data->subject->name)',
        'filter' => CHtml::dropDownList('Lecture[subject_id]',
                $model->subject_id, Chtml::ListData(Subject::model()->findAll('department_id='.$department_id),'id','name'),
                array('empty' => '(Select)'))

    )
/*    array(
        'name'=>'subject',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>"Subject::model()->find('id=2')->name",
        'filter'=>''
    ),*/


),
));
```

and in model the search function is

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('slide_num',$this->slide_num,true);
    $criteria->compare('type',$this->type,true);
    $criteria->compare('size',$this->size,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('subject_id',$this->subject_id);

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
    /*return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));*/
}
```

every thing is ok my target is filter that works in this search function correctly but i want to have a condition in criteria
    `$criteria->condition='subject_id=1 or subject_id=3';`
 when i put the condition in criteria its filter don't work any solution for having condition in search function and its filter work too

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('slide_num',$this->slide_num,true);
    $criteria->compare('type',$this->type,true);
    $criteria->compare('size',$this->size,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('subject_id',$this->subject_id);
    $criteria->condition='subject_id=1 or subject_id=3';
    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
    /*return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$criteria->condition='subject_id=1 or subject_id=3';`

try

```
$criteria->addCondition("subject_id = 1");
$criteria->addCondition("subject_id = 2", "OR");
```

OR JUST

```
$criteria->addInCondition("subject_id", array("1","2"));
```